# How to fetch records from table where coloumn1(State) and Column(city) having common and different values

Tags: sql

Suppose a table Geogrpahy in which 1st column is 'State' and 2nd column is 'CITY' like as below:-

```
State  City
S1      C1
S2      C2
S3      C3
S4      C2
S1      C1
S2      C3
S3      C4
S9      C2
```

How to get having states with multiple cities?

How to get state with common cities?

Comment: Don't forget to specify the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Guys, i am clueless still, how it will be done ? Multiple options coming in mind that by GROUP BY CLAUSE.

Comment: is it worksSELECT count(distinct column1), column2
FROM tableName
GROUP BY column2
HAVING count(distinct column1) > 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case state and city combination is mutliple times in the table eg(S1,C1). so fist group the table to get distinct of both combination

So query to get states that have multiple cities will be like

```
SELECT        States, COUNT(City) AS NoofCities
FROM            (SELECT        States, City
                          FROM            Geogrpahy
                          GROUP BY States, City) AS TT
GROUP BY States  having COUNT(City)>1
```

And to get the cities which are present in other states also do the below

```
select States,City from Geogrpahy  as geography1 where City in (select City from Geogrpahy where Geogrpahy.States!=geography1.States)
```

Again if you want to get the  state only  then group it to states

Comment: Happy to know it but can u mark it answer so that somebody else can refer

Answer (score 1):

```
--Microsoft SQL Specific:
--States with multiple cities
SELECT [State] ,count (distinct [City]) as Cities_Count
   FROM [dbo].[Geogrpahy]
   group by [State]
   having count (distinct [City]) > 1


--Cities in multiple States

select * from [Geogrpahy]
where [City] in (
select [City] from (
SELECT [City] ,count (distinct [State]) as State_Count
       FROM [dbo].[Geogrpahy]
       group by [City]
       having count (distinct [State]) > 1) a)
order by City, [State]
```

Comment: You should mention that this syntax is Microsoft specific and non-standard.

Comment: yes it works fine for cities having multiple states thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use below query to get states having multiple cities

```
SELECT State  , COUNT(*) AS NO_OF_City FROM Geogrpahy 
GROUP BY State  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY State  ;
```

Comment: Have changed it

Comment: Thanks JIM, i will try it and let you know :)

Comment: S1 2
S2 2
S3 2    when i used this query it gives this o/p, it gives no, of records which is OK, but S1 having multiple cities both have name C1 so it dispalyed as no_of_city =2 for S1,which having both record in city as 'C1'

Comment: In this case, you can use count(distinct City) instead of count(*)